# Azure Synapse Analytics Workspace -- how to move body of code, connections, etc., from one workspace to another

Tags: azure, import, export, azure-synapse

We are moving a body of code from one subscription to another.  It's not huge, but it's big enough that we'd like to find a way to bulk move it so that we don't forget anything.  It won't go automatically, so we're looking to move it by hand in as controllable fashion as we can manage.

We have an empty Azure Synapse Analytics Workspace in the new subscription.  How do we best move the contents of the existing workspace into the new one?  I've been trying to find an Export/Import feature.  I've found "Download Support Files" on individual pipelines, but I don't know how to import them, or how to more or less say "Download All Files" to start.

Any help you can provide is appreciated.  We're new, so anything you can do to put us on the right screen with the right button to click would be invaluable.

Tried "Download Support Files" but couldn't figure out how to make it work, or how to expand it to the entire workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible to move Entire synapse workspace from one to another.

But you can import the notebook, pipeline and SQL code like below.

**Import pipeline:**

Click on **Export template** in the source synapse pipeline.

[image]

A zip file with pipeline name will be downloaded.

Now, go to target **synapse workspace** -> **Integrate** -> **+** -> **Import from pipeline template**.

[image]

Select the downloaded zip file and if the pipeline contains any dataset, it requires the linked service creation for it. During the import it asks to do that.

[image]

Create the linked service and click on **Open pipeline**.

[image]

The same pipeline will be created in the target synapse.

[image]

To import the notebook, click on export in the notebook and select the required format(`.py`/`.ipynb`).

[image]

The file with notebook name will be downloaded.

Go to **target synapse workspace** -> **Develop** -> **+** -> **Import**.

[image]

Select the file and notebook will be imported.

[image]

It is same for SQL script as well.